# difficulty with loops and dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have hit a mental road block here, or perhaps too much coding and cant think straight.

I have a simple program to model the output of a factor including existing factories with a known production profile (decays each year) along with new factories adding for the next few years.

The goal is to get a total production series which incorporates both.  Hopefully the comments in the code better indicate what my issues are.

```
import pandas as pd

#constants
inv_yr = 5  # years of making new investments
asset_life = 30 # years of production for new factor

# creates blank time series
new_factory_adds = pd.Series(0, index=range(1,asset_life + inv_yr +1), name = 'new factories')  

production = pd.Series(0, index=range(1,asset_life+1))  

# Fill series of new factory adds
for i in range(1, inv_yr+1):
    new_factory_adds[i] = 2  # means for first 5 years 2 are added each yr.

# Fill series of a new individual production line
    for j in range(1,asset_life+1):
    if j ==1:
        production[j] = 100
    else:
        production[j] = production[j-1]*0.95


# to calculate total production for each year...
# create blank time series        
tot_prod = pd.Series(0, index=range(1,asset_life + inv_yr+1),name='Tot Prod')  

# data frame to combined 
df = pd.concat([new_factory_adds,tot_prod],axis=1)
print(df)

# fill Tot Production series - this is where i am having difficuilties


for k in range(1, asset_life + inv_yr+1):
    if k ==1:
        tot_prod=new_factory_adds[k]*production[k]
    elif:
        k<=inv_yr:
            tot_prod=new_factory_adds[k]*production[k] + production[k-1]
```

Comment: Is this ```for j in range(1,asset_life+1):``` meant to be nested within ```for i in range(1, inv_yr+1):```?

Comment: @kerwei no. It’s separate. To fill the number of new factories added each year.